# Is this (clever) spam?

Tags: discussion

Looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/970302/11720) and the answer, it looks like spam to me:

- Both users have 1 point only.
- Both have women as avatars.
- Both link to the same blogspot blog.
- Both the question and answer lacks quality IMHO.

Maybe I read too much into things but to me it looks suspicious.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nice catch - they were spammers.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Assuming ████████ .com is genuine adware, would a de-spam linked version of the question with details moved from the site to the answer be useful, or are malware removal instructions too much of a moving target to be worthwhile?

Comment: @DanNeely: Most of the sites hawking malware removal crap have instructions that look like that -- generic pabulum that sounds like useful instructions, with lots of steps so it looks like a big job, followed by the simple alternative of just downloading their program.  If you remove the ad, the instructions often lack important details or contain steps like lots of registry changes.  There's no real value in the instructions when there are tested and trustworthy tools already covered in our canonical malware post.

Comment: Pretty much that. IMO nothing of value was lost, and considering it was a spam seed, meh, no point in preserving the *really* generic information in that question

Comment: Its not quite idiomatic English is tolerable, but the author's credibility is destroyed by not knowing the name of the Big G's web browser.  If *anything* can survive machine translation, that's it.